# Node.jsの開発におすすめなIDEを教えてください。

Tags: node.js

以下の機能を利用できるようなIDEがあれば教えてください。

- 関数名のコードヒント（ClassName. まで書けばクラス内の関数や定数がコードヒントで出るような機能）
- コード内で利用されているクラス・関数にジャンプする機能
- 特定の関数やクラスを利用しているプロジェクト内のファイルを検索する機能

aws-sdkなどの外部パッケージを利用して開発する際にリファレンスを探しながら開発をするのが辛いです。
さくっと利用しているクラスや関数のソースをみて開発できれば楽なのにと思って質問しました。

Comment: visual studioは試しましたか。どういったアプリケーションの開発をするのか不明ですが、ふつうのレベルならvsで十分すぎるとおもいます。そうでなければ、どういった開発においてこういう機能がないと致命的、など具体的に書いたほうがより良い候補が上がるかもしれません。

Comment: おすすめを聞く質問は主観的になりやすいので、よくない質問とされています。外せない機能や自分が最も慣れ親しんだIDEを一つ選びそれで欲しい機能をどう実現するかを聞く方が建設的で良い質問になると思います。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: 質問しておいて、メールでの通知を入れておらず気づきませんでした。申し訳ありません。